# How to write this SQL sub-query?

Tags: sql, subquery

I have this query which is running perfectly

From this query I am selecting all restaurant 3 KM from my location this is my 1st table.

```
SELECT foodjoint_id,foodjoint_name,open_hours,cont_no,address_line,city ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('".$userLatitude."') ) * cos( radians( foodjoint_latitude) ) * cos( radians( foodjoint_longitude) - radians('".$userLongitude."') ) + sin( radians('".$userLatitude."') ) * sin( radians( foodjoint_latitude) ) ) ) AS distance
FROM provider_food_joints
HAVING distance < '3' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20
```

But I need to select the AVG rating from those food joint which are with in this 3Km.

The query is also running perfectly:

```
select AVG(customer_ratings) from customer_review where foodjoint_id=".$foodjoint_id
```

but I need to add this two query through which I can select all those food joint and their rating AVG.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow :-) Highlight your query, then click the curly bracket, the fifth button starting from **B** **I** ...

Comment: As an additional stylistic note, you should not use quotes around integers (the '3' for distance).  It is misleading if you or anyone else goes back and looks at the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just place the subquery and you will get your result:

```
`SELECT foodjoint_id,foodjoint_name,open_hours,cont_no,address_line,city ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('".$userLatitude."') ) * cos( radians( foodjoint_latitude) ) * cos( radians( foodjoint_longitude) - radians('".$userLongitude."') ) + sin( radians('".$userLatitude."') ) * sin( radians( foodjoint_latitude) ) ) ) AS distance,

(select AVG(customer_ratings) from customer_review where customer_review.foodjoint_id=provider_food_joints.foodjoint_id) as Customer_Reviews

 FROM provider_food_joints 

HAVING distance < '3' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20`
```