# Sql Sub query need to add two query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query which is running perfectly last day answered by  Shaikh Farooque
[Link of that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10461209/sub-sql-query-please-help-me)

Now I have another problem I need to filter those foodjoint_id detail which are under the same  cuisine_id.
**User  going to submit lat long and cuisine_id I need to filter those FoodJoint**

As I told you I already search Food Joint by the Lat Long which is running now I need to add cuisine filter.

The query which is running is

```
SELECT foodjoint_id,foodjoint_name,open_hours,cont_no,address_line,city, 
( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('".$userLatitude."') ) * 
   cos( radians( foodjoint_latitude) ) * cos( radians( foodjoint_longitude) - 
   radians('".$userLongitude."') ) + sin( radians('".$userLatitude."') ) * 
   sin( radians( foodjoint_latitude) ) ) ) AS distance,
 (SELECT AVG(customer_ratings) 
 FROM customer_review 
 WHERE foodjoint_id=provider_food_joints.foodjoint_id) AS customer_rating 
 FROM provider_food_joints 
 HAVING distance < '3' ORDER BY distance
```

and I have added it with :

```
SELECT foodjoint_id FROM menu_item WHERE cuisine_id=''.$userGivenCuisineId.''
```

**I am sorry to say that the problem is still unsolved**

Comment: Can you more clearify your question

Comment: Kindly try the following answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT foodjoint_id,foodjoint_name,open_hours,cont_no,address_line,city, 
( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('".$userLatitude."') ) * 
   cos( radians( foodjoint_latitude) ) * cos( radians( foodjoint_longitude) - 
   radians('".$userLongitude."') ) + sin( radians('".$userLatitude."') ) * 
   sin( radians( foodjoint_latitude) ) ) ) AS distance,
(select AVG(customer_ratings) from customer_review where 
foodjoint_id=provider_food_joints.foodjoint_id) as customer_rating 
FROM provider_food_joints 
where  foodjoint_id in 
(SELECT foodjoint_id FROM menu_item WHERE cuisine_id='".$userGivenCuisineId."')
HAVING distance < '3' ORDER BY distance
```